# Sockets, communication stops

Tags: python, sockets, client

I have a simple question about socket programming. I've done to implement a server and two clients as following codes, but all of sudden it stops while it communicates each other. I have no idea why it happens all the time.

Would you give me advice, hint, or help?
Thank you for your time.

#### Client

```
# simple client

import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = ""
port = 12345

buf = 100

s.connect((host, port))
i = 0

timestep = 0

while(1):
    k = '01'#+str(timestep)
    #1
    s.send(k)
    print 'sending message is', k

    #2
    v = s.recv(buf)
    print v

    if v == 'hold 01':
        print 'timestep is', timestep#'send the previous message'
        if timestep == 0:
            timestep == 0
        else:
            timestep -= 1
    else:
        print 'read data'
        FILE = open("datainfo1.txt", "r+")
        msg = FILE.read()
        FILE.close()

        #3
        while(1):
            tmp, msg = msg[:buf], msg[buf:]

            s.send(tmp)

            print len(tmp)

            if len(tmp) < buf:
                print 'break'
                break
        # send file
    i+=1
    timestep+=1
print 'end'
s.close()
```

#### Server

```
import socket, sys 

# set up listening socket 
lstn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
host = ""
port = 12345

# bind lstn socket to this port 
lstn.bind(("", port)) 
lstn.listen(5) 

# initialize buffer size
buf = 100

# initialize concatenate string, v 
v = ''

# initialize client socket list 
cs = [] 
check = [0, 0]

# a fixed number of clients
nc = 1 

count = 0
status = [0,0]
j = 0
step = [0,0]

for i in range(nc): 
    (clnt,ap) = lstn.accept() 
    clnt.setblocking(0) 
    cs.append(clnt) 


file = open("output_analysis.txt","w+")

while (len(cs) > 0): 
    clnt = cs.pop(0) 
    cs.append(clnt) 

    try: 
        #1
        k = clnt.recv(buf)  
        print "k=",k,"\n"#[:2]  
        if k == '01':
            print "1st client connected", status[0]
            file.write("1st\t") 

            if status[0] == 0:
                v = 'hold 01'
                check[0] = 1
            elif status[0] == 1:
                v = 'go 01'
                # status[0] = 0

            print v, "the message\n"

            file.write(v)
            file.write("\t")
            #2
            clnt.send(v) 

            if status[0] == 1:

                FILE = open("client1.txt","w+")
                print 'receive 01'
                #3
                while(1):
                    status[0] = 0
                    print '1st : receiving'
                    msg = clnt.recv(buf)
                    print len(msg)

                    if len(msg) < buf:
                        print 'break'
                        #FILE.close()
                        break 



        elif k == '02':
            print "2nd client connected", status[0]
            file.write("2nd\t") 

            if status[1] == 0:
                v = 'hold 02'
                check[1] = 1
            elif status[1] == 1:
                v = 'go 02'
                # status[0] = 0

            print v, "the message\n"

            file.write(v)
            file.write("\t")
            #2
            clnt.send(v) 

            if status[1] == 1:

                FILE = open("client2.txt","w+")
                print 'receive 02'
                #3
                while(1):
                    status[1] = 0
                    print '2nd : receiving'
                    msg = clnt.recv(buf)
                    print len(msg)

                    if len(msg) < buf:
                        print 'break'
                        #FILE.close()
                        break 

        if check[0] == 1:# and check[1] == 1:
            print j, 'here\n'
            j += 1
            for i in range(2):
                check[i] = 0
                status[i] = 1 # which means, all clients are connected
            print check, status
        else:
            print 'hello'

    except: pass 

file.close()
lstn.close()
```

Comment: Having just one space for indentation makes your code hard to read.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What type of exception does it produce (if any)?

Comment: You should update your title. Simple question is not the best title I have seen..

Answer (score 3):

```
except: pass
```

You're ignoring all exceptions. This is a bad idea, because it doesn't let you know when things go wrong. You'll need to remove that `except` handler before you can reasonably debug your code.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is you are setting non-blocking mode:

> clnt.setblocking(0)

But never checking that it is safe to send or recv data.  It turns out that since the code is ignoring all exceptions, it isn't seeing the following error that I got when I removed the try:

> Exception [Errno 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately

After removing the `setblocking` call, the code proceeded further, but still has problems.

Describing what problem you are trying to solve would help to understand what the code is trying to do.